Substrate Public key and address derivation
Expected result:

mnemonic: "sample split bamboo west visual approve brain fox arch
impact relief smile" --scheme "ed25519" Secret phrase:       sample
split bamboo west visual approve brain fox arch impact relief smile
Network ID:        substrate
Secret seed:
0x9fa1ab1d37025d8c3cd596ecbf50435572eeaeb1785a0c9ed2b22afa4c378d6a
Public key (hex):
0x10b22ebe89b321370bee8d39d5c5d411daf1e8fc91c9d1534044590f1f966ebc
Account ID:
0x10b22ebe89b321370bee8d39d5c5d411daf1e8fc91c9d1534044590f1f966ebc
Public key (SS58): 5CSbZ7wG456oty4WoiX6a1J88VUbrCXLhrKVJ9q95BsYH4TZ
SS58 Address:      5CSbZ7wG456oty4WoiX6a1J88VUbrCXLhrKVJ9q95BsYH4TZ

Please guide, how to derive substrate public key in c?
Also, while I am trying to derive the account address from the know public key through c implementation:
https://github.com/Zondax/ledger-polkadot/blob/9d06c78f7ec1c096d2bccae863e932fbddde5a37/app/src/crypto_helper.c
  ...
  hex_string_to_byte_array(
  "10b22ebe89b321370bee8d39d5c5d411daf1e8fc91c9d1534044590f1f966ebc",
  64, pubkey);
  u8ToHexStr("public key manual", pubkey, PK_LEN_25519);

  // Get Account

  printf("\n\n");

  char address[100] = "";
  size_t address_size = sizeof(address);

  // get address func
  uint16_t outlen = crypto_SS58EncodePubkey(address, &address_size, 0, pubkey);
...

  int ss58hash(const unsigned char *in,
                 unsigned int inLen,
                 unsigned char *out,
                 unsigned int outLen) {
      blake2b_state s;
      blake2b_Init(&s, 64);
      blake2b_Update(&s, SS58_BLAKE_PREFIX, SS58_BLAKE_PREFIX_LEN);
      blake2b_Update(&s, in, inLen);
      blake2b_Final(&s, out, outLen);
      return 0;
    }
    
    uint16_t crypto_SS58EncodePubkey(char *buffer,
                                     uint16_t buffer_len,
                                     uint16_t addressType,
                                     const uint8_t *pubkey) {
      // based on https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/ss58/
      if (buffer == NULL || buffer_len < SS58_ADDRESS_MAX_LEN) {
        return 0;
      }
  if (pubkey == NULL) {
    return 0;
  }

  uint8_t hash[64] = {0};
  uint8_t unencoded[36] = {0};
  
  uint8_t prefixSize;
  if (addressType > 16383) {
    prefixSize = 0;
  }

  if (addressType > 63) {
    unencoded[0] = 0x40 | ((addressType >> 2) & 0x3F);
    unencoded[1] = ((addressType & 0x3) << 6) + ((addressType >> 8) & 0x3F);
    prefixSize = 2;
  } else {
    unencoded[0] = addressType & 0x3F;    // address type
    prefixSize = 1;
  }

  if (prefixSize == 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  memcpy(unencoded + prefixSize, pubkey, 32);    // account id
  u8ToHexStr("unencoded p", unencoded, 36);
  if (ss58hash((uint8_t *)unencoded, 32 + prefixSize, hash, 64) != 0) {
    memzero(unencoded, sizeof(unencoded));
    return 0;
  }
  unencoded[32 + prefixSize] = hash[0];
  unencoded[33 + prefixSize] = hash[1];

  u8ToHexStr("hash", hash, 64);
  u8ToHexStr("unencoded", unencoded, 36);

  char unencoded_str[36 * 2 + 1];
  u8ToHexStrr("unencoded str", unencoded, 36, unencoded_str);

  size_t outLen = buffer_len;
  if (b58enc(buffer, &buffer_len, unencoded_str, 34 + prefixSize) != true) {
    memzero(unencoded, sizeof(unencoded));
    return 0;
  }

  return outLen;
}

Getting following result:

public key:
0x10b22ebe89b321370bee8d39d5c5d411daf1e8fc91c9d1534044590f1f966ebc
hash:
0xf0a43f1e82a4cfb3fbf14a52a5b1fb9ee3467a752440ced68cc017af78121c73f1acb7c967de099503273c71ee720d420d5e028671003ddc7b3f01fd90d7dab2
unencoded str :
0x0010b22ebe89b321370bee8d39d5c5d411daf1e8fc91c9d1534044590f1f966ebcf0a400
address: 5osrKSRC5QMK6YDGTG7tBd2r7bxVp7148MKdejoeQRSKabF9

